# c# graphics.drawline on datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, datagridview

I have the following code:

```
using (Pen gridPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1))
        {
           if ((e.RowIndex % 4) == 0)
           {
               e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridPen, e.CellBounds.X, e.CellBounds.Top-1, e.CellBounds.Right-1, e.CellBounds.Top-1);
           }
        }
```

This does draw the grid lines on the datagridview every 4 rows (as required), but when I scroll on the datagridview the lines disappear, then sometimes re-appear again.  Anybody know why?  Thanks.

Comment: It could depend on the context. OnCellPainting is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it, Try to call `Invalidate` method for the DataGrid in `Scroll` event handler.

Good luck!